# Sending GPS location via GSM module

Tags: arduino, gps, gsm

I am using a SIM900A GSM module and a NEO-6m GPS module. I want to send the location via the GSM module when the GSM module receives a message.

My code is working when I am receiving and sending any message with the help of the GSM module, but it is not working when I join the two, i.e. GPS and GSM modules.

Here is my code for the two.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
// GPS
#include <TinyGPS.h>

// GSM
SoftwareSerial SIM900A(9, 10);
SoftwareSerial mySerial(5, 6);
TinyGPS gps;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SIM900A.begin(9600);
  SIM900A.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0");
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  bool newdata = false;
  String buffer = readSIM900A();
  if(SIM900A.available() > 0)
    Serial.println(SIM900A.read());
  if (buffer.startsWith("\r\n+CMT: ")) {
    // printing the number
    Serial.println(buffer.substring(9, 22));
    // Remove first 51 characters
    // buffer.remove(0, 51);
    int len = buffer.length();
    // printing message
    Serial.println(buffer.substring(51, len-2));
    if (buffer.substring(51, len-2) == "location") {
      Serial.println("Sending location");
      // GPS
      if (mySerial.available()) {
        char c = mySerial.read();
        if (gps.encode(c)) {
          newdata = true;
        }
      }
      if (newdata) {
        long int lat, lon;
        unsigned long age, age1, date, time, chars;
        gps.get_position(&lat, &lon, &age);
        gps.get_datetime(&date, &time, &age);
        Serial.print("Lat/Long(10^-5 deg): ");
        Serial.print(lat);
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(lon); 
        Serial.print(" Fix age: "); 
        Serial.print(age); Serial.println("ms.");
        Serial.print("Date(ddmmyy): "); Serial.print(date);
        Serial.print(" Time(hhmmsscc): ");
        Serial.print(time);
        Serial.print(" Fix age: "); Serial.print(age); 
        Serial.println("ms.");
        Serial.print("Alt(cm): "); Serial.print(gps.altitude());
        Serial.print(" Speed(mps): "); Serial.print(gps.f_speed_mps());
        // setting GSM module
        SIM900A.println("AT+CMGF=1"); //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
        delay(1000); // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
        // sending location from which code word had come
        SIM900A.println("AT+CMGS=\"" + buffer.substring(9, 22) + "\"\r");
        // Replace x with mobile number
        Serial.println("AT+CMGS=\"" + buffer.substring(9, 22) + "\"\r");
        delay(1000);
        SIM900A.print("Lat/Long(10^-5 deg): ");
        SIM900A.print(lat);
        SIM900A.print(", ");
        SIM900A.print(lon); 
        SIM900A.print(" Fix age: "); 
        SIM900A.print(age); SIM900A.println("ms.");
        SIM900A.print("Date(ddmmyy): "); SIM900A.print(date);
        SIM900A.print(" Time(hhmmsscc): ");
        SIM900A.print(time);
        SIM900A.print(" Fix age: "); SIM900A.print(age); 
        SIM900A.println("ms.");
        SIM900A.print("Alt(cm): "); SIM900A.print(gps.altitude());
        SIM900A.print(" Speed(mps): "); SIM900A.print(gps.f_speed_mps());
        SIM900A.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
        delay(1000);
      }
    }
  }
  delay(100);
}

String readSIM900A() {
  String buffer;
  while (SIM900A.available()) {
    char c = SIM900A.read();
    buffer.concat(c);
    delay(10);
  }
  return buffer;
}
```

Above is my final code when the GPS and GSM modules are handled together. They are working totally fine when they are handled separately.

Connections:

Connected Tx, Rx pin of SIM900A to 9, 10 of Arduino Nano respectively, and Tx, Rx of GPS module to 5, 6 respectively. And I also made ground common with Arduino.

Comment: Attach your connections and also the output that you received when you combine both. Not working is not specific

Comment: I am not getting any output in serial monitor.

Comment: Sorry I had uploaded another code. I just corrected that.

Comment: Yeah that's why i asked. please be careful before writing on SO or it will be misleading and waste of time

Comment: I had connected Tx, Rx pin of SIM900A to 9, 10 of Arduino nano respectively and Tx, Rx of GPS module to 5, 6 respectively. and also made ground common with Arduino.

Comment: Not yet. I will do it later and let you know about it. Thanks btw

Comment: It would work as you expect. Inform me if any problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <NeoSWSerial.h>
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <AltSoftSerial.h>
// GPS
#include <TinyGPS.h>

// GSM
static const int RXPin = 8, TXPin = 9;
AltSoftSerial SIM900A(RXPin, TXPin);

NeoSWSerial mySerial(5, 6);
TinyGPS gps;

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
SIM900A.begin(9600);
SIM900A.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0");
mySerial.begin(9600);
delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{
bool newdata = false;
String buffer = readSIM900A();
if(SIM900A.available() > 0)
  Serial.println(SIM900A.read());
if (buffer.startsWith("\r\n+CMT: "))
{
    // printing the number
    Serial.println(buffer.substring(9, 22)); 

    // Remove first 51 characters
    // buffer.remove(0, 51);
    int len = buffer.length();
    // Remove \r\n from tail
    // buffer.remove(len - 2, 2);
    // printing message
    Serial.println(buffer.substring(51, len-2));
    if (buffer.substring(51, len-2) == "location")
    {
      Serial.println("Sending location");

      // GPS
      if (mySerial.available()) 
      {
         char c = mySerial.read();
         if (gps.encode(c)) 
         {
            newdata = true;
         }
      }
      if (newdata)
      {
        long int lat, lon;
        unsigned long age, age1, date, time, chars;

        gps.get_position(&lat, &lon, &age);
        gps.get_datetime(&date, &time, &age);
        Serial.print("Lat/Long(10^-5 deg): ");
        Serial.print(lat);
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(lon); 
        Serial.print(" Fix age: "); 
        Serial.print(age); Serial.println("ms.");

        Serial.print("Date(ddmmyy): "); Serial.print(date); Serial.print(" 
        Time(hhmmsscc): ");
        Serial.print(time);
        Serial.print(" Fix age: "); Serial.print(age); 
        Serial.println("ms.");

        Serial.print("Alt(cm): "); Serial.print(gps.altitude());
        Serial.print(" Speed(mps): "); Serial.print(gps.f_speed_mps());

        // setting GSM module
        SIM900A.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
        delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
        // sending location from which code word had come
        SIM900A.println("AT+CMGS=\"" + buffer.substring(9, 22) + "\"\r"); // 
         Replace x with mobile number
        Serial.println("AT+CMGS=\"" + buffer.substring(9, 22) + "\"\r");
        delay(1000);

        SIM900A.print("Lat/Long(10^-5 deg): ");
        SIM900A.print(lat);
        SIM900A.print(", ");
        SIM900A.print(lon); 
        SIM900A.print(" Fix age: "); 
        SIM900A.print(age); SIM900A.println("ms.");

        SIM900A.print("Date(ddmmyy): "); SIM900A.print(date); 
        SIM900A.print(" Time(hhmmsscc): ");
        SIM900A.print(time);
        SIM900A.print(" Fix age: "); SIM900A.print(age); 
        SIM900A.println("ms.");

        SIM900A.print("Alt(cm): "); SIM900A.print(gps.altitude());
        SIM900A.print(" Speed(mps): "); SIM900A.print(gps.f_speed_mps());

        SIM900A.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
        delay(1000);
      }
    }
    }
    delay(100);
   }

 String readSIM900A()
{
String buffer;

while (SIM900A.available())
{
    char c = SIM900A.read();
    buffer.concat(c);
    delay(10);
}

return buffer;
}
```

P.S : I have changed the pins for GSM and rest part is same. Except adding `AltSoftSerial` it is a library same as `SoftwareSerial` (Download it from manage libraries and it requires pins 8 and 9). Don't change pin number in sketch change the connections.

Comment: Please feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: I don't think 8 is pwm pin arduino nano

Comment: So I don't think pin 8 can be used for the serial communication. Do you have any suggestion or explaination for that?

Comment: Try it. I have tested it on arduino uno it worked. 8 is not pwm on uno also.

Comment: Hey, It is not working, I tried the above code. I'm not getting any output again. Pin 8 is working, I think there is some other issue

Comment: I have just corrected the serial print issue. That's why there was nothing printing on screen. And if there is some other problem want to check it. But it might need your two basic codes too. And what's the problem now.

Comment: I got the problem. It was not working because we can't do multiple serial communication with more than one Tx, Rx. I just removed mySerial part and used Tx, Rx pin. Now it is working

Comment: Yeah it was the problem. I understood it, the first day i saw your program. But the edit i made in your program was a bit mistake. Sorry for that. Check it now, I used another library ( That was what i was supposed to do, but by mistake i took another library). It will work now.